# git use up space even when file is unstaged

Tags: git

I wanted to use `git-lfs` to add a large binary into my git repository but that failed:

```
$ git add large-file.tar.xz
```

So I unstage the file

```
$ git checkout -- large-file.tar.xz
$ git status
On branch lfs
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

But the git still use up the disk space for the large file.

```
$ du -sh .git
101M    .git
```

### Reclaiming the space

I tried using the [BFG repo cleaner](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/) to remove the blob, but nothing is found. (Yes, BFG only scan for existing commits, but I was desperate)

```
$ bfg --strip-blobs-bigger-than 10M .

Using repo :path/to/project

Scanning packfile for large blobs: 725
Scanning packfile for large blobs completed in 31 ms.
Warning : no large blobs matching criteria found in packfiles - does the repo need to be packed?
```

`git gc` does not work as well

```
$git reflog expire --expire=now --all && git gc --prune=now --aggressive
$ du -sh .git
101M    .git
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't forget to delete the original objects left as a backup by any bfg or filter-branch operation.

```
rm -Rf .git/refs/original
```

Then you can prune the rest:

```
git reflog expire --expire=now --all
git gc --prune=now
git gc --aggressive --prune=now
git repack -Ad      # kills in-pack garbage
git prune           # kills loose garbage
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below commands. It will remove loose objects from .git

```
git reflog expire --expire=now --all 
git repack -ad  # will remove loose objects from compressed objects
git prune       # remove loose objects
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Checking out a file doesn't unstage it. Use:

```
git reset HEAD large-file.tar.xz
git prune
```